# How to open and pass data from Native Android App to Flutter Android App?

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, native

I wants to open and get some data like (userid, token, etc.) in Flutter Android app from Native Android app.

I know that using Intent I can open and pass data with Package Name but how to retrieve in Flutter App?

How to make it possible?

[image: Open Flutter app from Native App]

Comment: Do you want open app by Native call ? and also pass data when you are open it?

Comment: Yes @NikhilVadoliya

Comment: look the intent documentation, probably in flutter you have just the same classes. PLUS both native and flutter apps must be installed on device for this to work

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos, Yes but how can I get passed parameter in Flutter App?

Comment: @SagarZala have you solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can open app by below code

```
//open app if app no background /killed
 val intent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.packageName)
 intent!!.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
 context.startActivity(intent)
```

If you want to pass data from Native to Flutter then you should be implement `MethodChannel`/`EventChannel`

Refer below link for Native to Flutter [Native to Flutter communication](https://blog.testfairy.com/native-communication-with-a-callback-in-flutter/)